# winform login check from database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I made a login form for an application, and I want to check if the login data from the user exists in the database so that he can log in successfully or display an message telling him that his login details are wrong.

I tried the `OleDbDataReader` but that didn't work, so I added a username and password in my database (in the table `Etudiant`) and tried to count the number of rows in the table `Etudiant`, so that the login succeeds if the count is greater than 0, otherwise "wrong details" is shown. But the problem is always the same, only the second message is shown.

Here's my code:

```
string strcnn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=app.mdb";
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(strcnn);
cnn.Open();
string reqet = "SELECT count(*) FROM Etudiant";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(reqet, cnn);
int x = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (x>0)
    MessageBox.Show("Bienvenu cher étudiant");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Données invalides !");

cnn.Close();
```

Comment: A part from the missing where clause on username and password, how many records are present in your table? If it returns always zero then you don't have any record or the database opened is not the one your think

Comment: To debug why it is not working I would change the ExecuteScalar into an ExecuteReader and remove the count from the select. That will let you can see user details are being returned.

Answer (score 2):

You must check the `username` and `password` on your query or it will return the full table row count, someting like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Etudiant WHERE User=(username) AND Password=(password)`.

Comment: thats what i really need to do in the select, but it didn't work so i tried even to count the rows number in the table and alays the same problem.
PS: i have two rows in that table

Comment: How are you passing username and password to your query? it should work if user and password match

Comment: here's the exact first code, what's wrong with it ? I'm writing a valid login information but it never works !

    string strcnn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=app.mdb";
                OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(strcnn);
                cnn.Open();
                string reqet = "SELECT cin,nce FROM Etudiant WHERE cin='" + utilisateur_box.Text + "' AND nce='"+motdepasse_box.Text+"'";

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(reqet, cnn);
                int x = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                
                if (x>0)
                    MessageBox.Show("Bienvenu cher étudiant");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Données invalides !","Connexion",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                cnn.Close();

Comment: You are doing an ExecuteScalar which works with results of only one value and are selecting cin and nce, so if you do "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Etudiant WHERE cin='" + utilisateur_box.Text + "' AND nce='"+motdepasse_box.Text+"'"; should work as expected

Comment: thankyou for answering me, but i found that i had a problem with my database :)